# Using like Function to paste values in Column

Tags: r

I'm trying to check if a value like `"LTL"` exists in a particular column & if it does paste `"LTL"` in the `TI2$Type` column if not paste `"None"`

Code

```
TI2$Type <- ifelse(TI2$coms_courier_id %like% "%LTL%", paste("LTL"), paste("None"))
```

But, it is just pasting "None" in `TI$Type` even though the column `coms_courier_id` has values like `"SL__2800__LTL"`.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Does `TI2$Type <- ifelse(grep("LTL", TI2$coms_courier_id) ,paste("LTL"),paste("None"))` work?

Comment: or `... "LTL" %in% TI2$coms_courier_id ...`? There is no `%like%` operator in R IMHO

Comment: `%like%` is not a base R function. Please include the `library` you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `%like%` operator, but you can `str_detect()` from the `stringr` package to get the result you're looking for.

```
library(stringr)
TI2$Type <- ifelse(str_detect(TI2$coms_courier_id, "LTL"), paste("LTL"), paste("None"))
```